# jQuery's :nth-child and :first-child selecting wrong element

Tags: jquery, css, soundmanager2

I am using a combination of Soundmanager2 and RoyalCarousel to get a playlist style carousel working. My goal now is to make it so that when a specific slide is selected, either through use of the back/forward buttons or the 'skip to' links, the appropriate song plays.
This works for all except the first slide, which consistently triggers the last slide to start playing. Triggering the last slide also triggers the last slide, so it's not like these two are reversed.
To see this in action.
http://ably.ca/hootch

```
$(".rsNavItem").live('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).index() + 1;
  $(".rsContainer div:nth-child("+ id +") .ui360 .sm2-360btn").click();
});
```

I've checked and rechecked everything here, :nth-child(1) selects :nth-child(9) every single time. Even testing for id == 1 and using first-child doesn't work...
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you recreate in jsfiddle?

Comment: what're the necessary steps in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. A UL can only have an LI as it's child. You have a UL with DIV child elements and LI elements within DIV elements too.

Comment: @BillyMoat - where is the `ul` with `div` child elements? There's nothing wrong with having a `div` inside a `li` item. Actually, scratch that - the generated code does indeed end up malformed.

Comment: You might start by addressing the issue @BillyMoat raises, using the `li` elements as the slides rather than wrapping them in a `div`. It might be the case that the plugin does this for you, but you should be able to change that behaviour. Else pick a different carousel. That will make life much easier trying to target each slide.

Comment: What is malformed exactly? I'm not seeing the problem...

Comment: If I view the source of your page the HTML actually looks okay. But if you inspect the rendered code by using Firebug or similar you'll see the malformed HTMl I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not big on Firebug ( i use web developer and Safari's dev tools mostly) I've got it installed and 'inspecting' now, where should I be seeing this malformation? thx!

Comment: Your `ul` should only have `li` items as direct descendants. Check it out in your chosen inspection tool and you'll see that each `li` is in fact wrapped in a `div`.

Comment: `$(".rsContainer div:nth-child(1) .ui360 .sm2-360btn")` results in a collection of 9 elements 
while `$(".rsContainer div:nth-child(2) .ui360 .sm2-360btn")` gives only one. I suspect you must check the selector. 
The porblem seems to be with the class `.rsContainer`

Comment: Raffael's comment just goes to show that something is messed up, right? I mean, how can the first return 9 elements and the second return one? Is that really a markup issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var rsContainer = $('.rsContainer');
$('.rsNavItem').live('click', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();

    $('.rsSlide:eq(' + index + ') .ui360 .sm2-360btn', rsContainer).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but I don't like it...

```
$(".rsNavItem").live('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).index();
  soundManager.stopAll();
  $(".rsContainer").children().each(function(){
      if ($(this).index() == id) {
          $(this).find(".ui360 .sm2-360btn").click();
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

Instead of using :nth-child, I've decided to try iterating through all the child elements and checking the index of the 'skip-to' link against the index of the slides, then using find() to hit the button as before...
I don't like it because it's a loop... seems like more of a performance hit versus :nth-child...

Answer (score 0):

when you are targeting

```
$(".rsContainer div:nth-child(1) ...
```

you are getting nothing less than 37 results !

That's all the div that are the first child of their parent, however deep nested they are.

I guess that what you mean is

```
$(".rsContainer > div:nth-child(1) ...
```

(direct descendant, not any level descendant)